# fminbnd gives a value that is not a minimum seen on the plot

Tags: matlab

I am trying to find the minimum F and its corresponding x-axis values by using fminbnd. However, when I marked this minimum value on the plot, it is not an minimum at all. The code I used is below:

```
T = 726.85; 

kB = 8.61e-5;

Fe_energy = 0;

O_energy_Joule = -175.100 + 50.16*T;
O_energy = O_energy_Joule*6.242e18; 

syms c;
f = c*O_energy + (1-c)*Fe_energy + kB*T*(c.*log(c) + (1-c).*log(1-c));
F = matlabFunction(f);
x = fminbnd(F, 0, 1)

c = (0:1e-7:1e-4);
R = c*O_energy + (1-c)*Fe_energy + kB*T*(c.*log(c) + (1-c).*log(1-c));
plot(c, R)
hold on
plot(x,F(x),'x')
```

The result of the code is here:
[plot and minimum point](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9h4Ne.jpg)
Can someone help with answering where the discrepancy comes from? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A good thing about matlab optimization functions is that you can set some usefull options and see what the optimizer does.

I don't have the symbolic toolbox, so I put your function into a separate file:

```
options = optimset('Display','iter');
x = fminbnd(@myfun, 0, 1, options);
```

Here is the optimizer output:

```
   16    0.000453104   1.0262e+20        golden
   17    0.000280034  6.34228e+19        golden
   18     0.00017307  3.91974e+19        golden
   19    0.000106963  2.42254e+19        golden
   20     6.6107e-05  1.49721e+19        golden

Optimization terminated:
 the current x satisfies the termination criteria using OPTIONS.TolX of 1.000000e-04
```

Have a look at the termination criteria.

Now put your own termination criteria into the options and execute the code:

```
options = optimset('Display','iter', 'TolX', 1e-7);
x = fminbnd(@myfun, 0, 1, options);
```

The output:

```
   31    3.32187e-07  7.52347e+16        golden
   32    2.05303e-07  4.64976e+16        golden
   33    1.26884e-07  2.87371e+16        golden
   34    7.84188e-08  1.77605e+16        golden
   35    4.50855e-08  1.02111e+16        golden

Optimization terminated:
 the current x satisfies the termination criteria using OPTIONS.TolX of 1.000000e-07
```

[image: Using fminbnd. Setting your own termination criteria]

Comment: To clarify: TolX is a lower bound on the size of a step.  So if you get within TolX of your bound with a gradient pointed away from the bound it's going to stop.  There are other stopping criteria that you can use as well if putting a limit on the step size is unacceptable for your application.

Comment: You are right in a general case, but for this function it's a legal option. Its derivative is never equal to zero, so there is no local minima where the optimizer could stuck.